# why this Code can't run in Java?

Tags: java, android, c, pcm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [unsigned short in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841461/unsigned-short-in-java)
>   [Conversion of Audio Format in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515174/conversion-of-audio-format-in-java)

i Have a code which convert ulaw music to pcm format

The Code is programed by C , but now, i need it run in java

the Code is like this

```
short ALG_ulawDecode(unsigned short input)
{
unsigned short isNegative;

short nOut;

isNegative = ((input & 0x80) == 0);
if (isNegative)
    nOut = 127 - input;
else
    nOut = 255 - input;
if (nOut < 2)
    nOut *= 2;
else if (nOut < 16)
    nOut = ((nOut - 1) << 1) + 1 + 1;
else if (nOut < 32)
    nOut = ((nOut - 16) << 2) + 2 + 31;
else if (nOut < 48)
    nOut = ((nOut - 32) << 3) + 4 + 95;
else if (nOut < 64)
    nOut = ((nOut - 48) << 4) + 8 + 223;
else if (nOut < 80)
    nOut = ((nOut - 64) << 5) + 16 + 479;
else if (nOut < 96)
    nOut = ((nOut - 80) << 6) + 32 + 991;
else if (nOut < 112)
    nOut = ((nOut - 96) << 7) + 64 + 2015;
else
    nOut = ((nOut - 112) << 8) + 128 + 4063;
if (isNegative)
    nOut = -nOut;
nOut <<= 2;
return nOut;
}
```

It just can't run due to 『unsigned short』are not supported in Java

is anyone have some advice?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Write C or C++.  You can't have an unsigned short in Java.

Answer (score 2):

The best advice anyone can give you is to go read an introduction to Java tutorial or book.

As the error states, `unsigned short` is not a primitive in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't have signed and unsigned types.  Remove the unsigned and used signed shorts, the rest of the code should still work.

Answer (score 1):

`char` is grammatically equivalent to `unsigned short` in Java. However, you'd better not use it for any public methods as it is semantically not an integer type.

If you want to use `unsigned short`, I think `int` fits. You can just use the lowest 16 bits of it.